# Met Uncaught (in promise) RuntimeError: index out of bounds in Emscripten

Tags: emscripten

I Use Emscripten's emcmake to compile my C project.

When I opened the generated webpage, I got the error:

[image: the picture from browser Firefox]

text of above picture

Uncaught (in promise) RuntimeError: index out of bounds    createExportWrapper http://localhost:63342/new_exp/emsdk-build/executable.js:1165    callMain http://localhost:63342/new_exp/emsdk-build/executable.js:9815    doRun http://localhost:63342/new_exp/emsdk-build/executable.js:9869    run http://localhost:63342/new_exp/emsdk-build/executable.js:9884    runCaller http://localhost:63342/new_exp/emsdk-build/executable.js:9800    removeRunDependency http://localhost:63342/new_exp/emsdk-build/executable.js:1086    receiveInstance http://localhost:63342/new_exp/emsdk-build/executable.js:1253    receiveInstantiationResult http://localhost:63342/new_exp/emsdk-build/executable.js:1271    promise callback*createWasm/instantiateAsync/< http://localhost:63342/new_exp/emsdk-build/executable.js:1312    promise callback*instantiateAsync http://localhost:63342/new_exp/emsdk-build/executable.js:1304    createWasm http://localhost:63342/new_exp/emsdk-build/executable.js:1341     http://localhost:63342/new_exp/emsdk-build/executable.js:9333executable.wasm:384544:1

I run this C project on Linux(**not using Emscripten**), check it with sanitizers and all runs well.

I find the problem might be caused by:

```c
uint64_t i; 
char     text[1024];    
FILE* fp = stdout;

fprintf(fp, "CAPACITY %" PRIu64 ", ELE_SIZE %" PRIu64 ", BUCKET_SIZE %" PRIu64 "\n", map->buckets_capacity, map->ele_size, map->bucket_size);
fprintf(fp, "USER_DATA 0x%p\n", map->user_data);    
fprintf(fp, "%6s\t%16s\tDATA\n", "psl", "HASH");    
for (i = 0; i < map->buckets_capacity; i++) {       
    _bucket_t *bucket;      

    /* error happened on the line below */      
    bucket = (_bucket_t *) ((char *) map->buckets_ + i * map->bucket_size); /*original: hashmap_bucket_at_(map, map->buckets_, i);*/    
    
    if (bucket->psl) print_data(hashmap_bucket_data_(bucket), text, 1024);      
    else text[0] = '\0';    
    fprintf(fp, "%6u\t%16lu\t%s\n", bucket->psl, bucket->hash, text);   
}
```

The memory is allocated by:

```c
map->buckets_  = malloc(map->bucket_size * map->buckets_capacity);
```

where *bucket_size* is 144, and *bucket_capacity* is 16.

I have used "-s ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH=1" and "-fsanitize=address" **when use Emscripten** when this error occurs.I don't know why this happened.

Comment: You're asking us to debug code we cannot see based on a vague description of that code. *contains some math calculations* is an absolute waste of keystrokes. If you want help debugging your code, paste your **actual code** into your post. See [ask] and [mre], and then [edit] your post. If you can't provide the code in the form of a [mre], we can't help you.

Comment: Sorry, now it is revised.

Comment: And that code is much more than *some math calculations*. It has a loop in it, which is where the error is happening. Use a debugger to step through the code to figure out where your logic error is - an index out of bounds error means that you're going off then end of the list or collection or array. As you've failed to provide a [mre] (which is clear because there are variables in use that are not declared in the code you posted), it's impossible to tell where the problem is located.

Comment: And as a note: If you're getting an index out of bounds error, it is not *all running well*. It's generating a runtime error.

Comment: This runs well on Linux without Emscripten.

Comment: I use Valgrind to check the executable generated by gcc and get no problem. But on Emscripten I do not know how to debug it and get the problem. That makes me confused.

Comment: After I did something else, I came back to see this and find that:`fprintf(fp, "%6u\t%16lu\t%s\n", bucket->psl, bucket->hash, text) `

Where `bucket->hash` has a type `uint64_t` .

After I change  **%lu** to **%"PRIu64"**, no problems appear anymore.

How should this happened?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248820/discussion-between-amias-and-ken-white).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```c
fprintf(fp, "%6u\t%16lu\t%s\n", bucket->psl, bucket->hash, text);
```

Where `bucket->hash` has a type `uint64_t` .

After I change  **%lu** to **%"PRIu64"**, no problems appear anymore.